# crontab not running wget

Tags: cron, wget

So I'm trying to run a `wget` command using crontab every 5 minutes. My problem that I have is it's just not running. I did `crontab -l` to see what was running, the command is there.

the command is: `wget --output-document="/Users/proudowner/Desktop/tfgo/bp.json" http://backpack.tf/api/IGetMarketPrices/v1/?key=<key>`

And the error log says: `/bin/sh: wget: command not found`

The command also runs fine without `crontab`.

Comment: path the cron job uses does not have wget in it, but you do - solution: give cronjob the full path to wget

Comment: So does that mean i'd have to path it to a .sh file or something with the command inside of it?

Comment: `whereis wget` should find the path

Comment: in my case you would end up with a cronjob `/usr/bin/wget --output-document="/Users/proudowner/Desktop/tfgo/bp.json" http://backpack.tf/api/IGetMarketPrices/v1/?key=55085a94ba8d88d1538b457` but your windows so what ever th path to the executable is

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In `crontab -e`, make this your first line:

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

Then `wget` should work without specifying the full path.

You can also just specify the full path to `wget` (`which wget` to find it):

```
/usr/bin/wget --output-document="/Users/proudowner/Desktop/tfgo/bp.json" http://backpack.tf/api/IGetMarketPrices/v1/?key=55085a94ba8d88d1538b4576
```